# where to instantiate logging class to log all logs of a request once?

Tags: asp.net, logging, event-handling

there is a **logging class** that logs user **activities** into a database .

as I didn't wanted to write logging codes in all methods ( violating **SRP principle** if I'm not wrong ) , I decided to define **events** and raise them in methods .

then add a class that contains **event handling methods** to **subscribe** to events and use logging class to log necessary data into database.

another point is that during a request **several** events may raise and I want to **catch them all** and add logs to the database in one **transaction** .

now I wonder **where** and **how** should I **instantiate** this handling class to achieve this goal ?

I'm using `Asp.net WebForms` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SRP would not be violated by adding logging statements into your methods.

You shouldn't re-invent the wheel unless you have a very specific need. Use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or some other logging framework.

Comment: doesn't adding a new task to a method violates SRP ? can you explain why not ? thanks . any way this is just one reason , another is to have a cleaner code and being able to manage code better and ...

Comment: @mohsen.d: it wouldn't be the method's task to actually do the logging. it's not any different from adding an event raising statement instead.